# Palfy's theorem for nilpotent groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, permutation-groups

P. P. Palfy proved that a primitive solvable subgroup of $S_n$ has order bounded by $24^{-1/3} n^{3.24399\dots}$ (in: Pálfy, P. P.
A polynomial bound for the orders of primitive solvable groups. 
J. Algebra 77 (1982), no. 1, 127–137. )

This is sharp (and notice that for $n$ prime, the affine group of the line (all transformations of the form $x \rightarrow a x + b$ is solvable, and is of order $O(n^2)$

I seem to be unable to find any sort of analogue for nilpotent groups (there are results on large nilpotent groups, but these are presumably [by Palfy's theorem!) NOT primitive, nor even transitive).

Comment: Nilpotent groups are not even semiprimitive, see http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869307005704, Lemma $2.3$.

Comment: @Dietrich: thanks! But notice that I hedged by saying "some analogue"... Maybe just transitive?

Comment: you mean that the ORDER is bounded (above), not the degree, right?

Comment: If you take $n=2^k$, then a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $S_n$ will be transitive... and it is rather large. It has order  $$2^{1+2+4+8+\cdots 2^{k-1}}=2^{2^k-1}\sim \exp(n).$$ So I feel like you'll need more than just transitivity to say anything very much...

Comment: @NickGill Yes, fixed (re degree). Otherwise, yes, you are right, but what is the right condition to get a sensible result?

Comment: @Igor, I don't know! Good question! Something stronger than transitive and weaker than semi-primitive... Goodness only knows. Will rack brains...

Comment: One dumb comment: there are examples of primitive nilpotent groups, namely cyclic groups of order a prime $p$, inside $S_p$. I guess it's clear enough that these are the only primitive nilpotent groups so the bound is linear in this case. I guess that's not what you're really after though...

Comment: @NickGill Your comment is quite relevant, and the "clear enough" is only mod the lemma in the paper Dietrich suggested...

Comment: @Igor, proving these are the only nilpotent primitives can be done easily from first principles. Maybe I'll write down an answer as it would be too long for a comment.

Answer (score 2):

This answer fleshes out observations made in comments above. The result below is an analogue of Palfy's theorem for nilpotent primitive groups, as requested.

> **Prop**. Let $N<S_n$ be a nilpotent primitive group. Then $n$ is prime and $N$ is cyclic of order $n$.

**Proof**. Since $N$ is nilpotent, a minimal normal subgroup $E$ of $N$ is elementary-abelian of order $p^a$. Since $N$ is primitive it must be transitive and, since $E$ is abelian, it must act regularly - so $n=p^a$. Indeed $E$ must be the unique minimal normal subgroup of $N$ because if there another, $E'$ say, then $E'$ would centralize $E$ and $EE'$ would be a transitive abelian subgroup of $S_n$ of order greater than $n$, which is impossible.

Now, since $E$ is unique, we conclude that $C_N(E)=E$. In particular if $g$ is an element of order coprime to $p$, then $g\not\in C_N(E)$. But this contradicts the fact that $N$ is nilpotent. Thus $N$ is a $p$-group. Then $N$ acts on $E$ via linear transformations and so $N/E$ is a $p$-subgroup of $GL_a(p)$ and, in particular, fixes a 1-dimensional subspace of $E$. This subspace is normal in $N$ and hence, since $N$ is primitive, is transitive. i.e. $E$ is itself 1-dimensional, i.e. $E=C_p$ with $n=p$. But, since $N$ is a $p$-group inside $S_p$ we conclude that $N=E=C_p$ as required.        **QED**

In fact, rather than primitivity, all I've used here is that $N$ has no intransitive normal subgroups. This property is called *quasiprimitivity* - it is a little weaker than primitivity.

There is an interesting sort of strong converse to this result which also sheds light on the original question.

> **Prop**. Let $n$ be a prime and $N<S_n$ be a nilpotent transitive group. Then $N$ is cyclic of order $n$.

**Proof**. Since $N$ is transitive it contains a cyclic subgroup $C$ of order $n$. But $C_{S_n}(C)=C$ and so $N$ must be an $n$-group. But then $N=C$, as required. **QED**

This result, along with the example given above in the comments - a Sylow $2$-subgroup when $n=2^k$ - demonstrate that bounding the order of a nilpotent transitive group is strongly dependent on the prime factorization of $n$. It's not clear to me whether there is a natural stronger condition than transitivity that will hold for any $n$...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read the following paper by Pálfy.  I don't have it handy here and it doesn't seem to be downloadable, but I recall he surveys similar results on the orders of nilpotent permutation groups.

Péter P. Pálfy, 
Estimations for the order of various permutation groups, 
*Contributions to general algebra*, 12 (Vienna, 1999), 37–49, Heyn, Klagenfurt, 2000.